# How safe is ASP.net code under App_Code directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to turn one of my form applications into a web form using ASP.net (C# backside). It is my understanding that the App_Code directory will protect code behind if the classes are underneath the directory.

**How safe are classes under this directory? Are they somewhat safe against people stealing the source?**

I know with .net form applications you can run the reflector software on them to get the full source... unless you obfuscate the file (to make it more difficult).

Comment: why do you need the App_Code directory. When you create an application in ASP.NET, it provides you with a full deployment package that only includes DLLs and ASPX forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the ASP.NET application folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294407/understanding-the-asp-net-application-folders)

Comment: @progrAmmar Oh duh, I forgot I figured out how to properly build the full package for my ASP project. But I guess this question would proceed with asking if the dll file would be protected? Can I obfuscate this without causing any issues? (I've only obfuscated exe files)

Comment: There is no reason to obfuscate anything. It all runs from a server. User never has access to any `.cs` files. Also obfuscation doesn't really "protect" you. It just makes life a little bit more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes (or files) in the *App_Code* directory are compiled into an assembly with automatically generated name. Even if you deploy a non-precompiled Web Site, it will be automatically compiled during first run.

In addition, App_Code (as well as App_Data, etc.) is not available by a direct URL. E.g. it is impossible to get any file using the following URL:
*http://mywebsite.com/App_Code/KnownFileName.cs* 
Moreover, IIS has many filters that prohibit requests to *.ascx, *.asax, *.cs, *.vb, *csproj, *vbproj, *.mdb and many other files. See Request Filtering feature in Web Site settings in IIS Manager for details.

So, your code is in safe unless you changed default ASP.NET or IIS settings.